# Firebase Unity password authentication failed

Tags: c#, authentication, unity-game-engine, firebase

The creation of a user with email and password fails and I can't find the source of the problem.

I'm using "Firebase Unity SDK" with the auth and database packages.

I followed this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/password-auth) on the Firebase web page.

This is the C# code I use in my Unity project.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase.Auth;

public class FirebaseAuthEmail : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string email = "abc@gmail.com";
    public string password = "abccbe123321";

    void Start()
    {
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(
            task => {
                if (!task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    // User created
                    Debug.Log("User created");
                }
                else
                {
                    // User creation failed
                    Debug.Log("User creation failed");
                }
                if (task.IsCanceled) { Debug.Log("Task canceled"); }
                if (task.IsFaulted) { Debug.Log("Task faulted"); }
            });
    }
}
```

When I press the play button i get "User creation failed" and "Task faulted".

I've successfully managed to add entries to the database but not to create an authenticated user.

And yes I've [enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH4xg.png) Email/Password in the Firebase console.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase Auth doesn't work on Unity Editor.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/3